# API call from one site to another - same IIS Server

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to make API call from one website to API - both located on same server. When I run it on my machine - I am able to get results if calling API from localhost. When I publish it to the server - I am not getting any results. Can't debug code on server side - do not have tools for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be firewall that's not letting the request go through. If it is a REST API that you're calling, you can try [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) and test your API. If you are able to get the result, then there could be something wrong with the call you're making.

Comment: it works with postman, will need figure out why it is not working on IIS.

Comment: issue was in my web.config file

Comment: @Ika what was the issue in your web.config file?